# Django REST Framework token login also works with less fields than I have determined

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

So I have a **Django REST Framework** login, and I determindes, that the user need the `phone_number`, `username` and `password`

user/serializers.py

```py
[...]
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['phone_number', 'username', 'first_name', 'country', 'email', 'password', 'password2']


        
        extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True},
                'username': {'required': True},
                'phone_number': {'required': True}
        }   
[...]
```

But with postman, I can make a post request without the `phone_number` field and nevertheless I get the token from the Token authentication :/

Postman:

[image]

### Edit

My URLs now look like this, but it still won't work:
user/api/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import(
    registration_view,
)
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token



from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })





app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', registration_view, name="register"),
    path('login/', CustomAuthToken.as_view(), name="login"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check if the values are there in `class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):`, but have you registered your custom User model in settings.py?

Comment: Hey, yeah, I have a custom User Model. But CustomAuthToken wont work for me. Can you help meß

Comment: You can check if all fields are there inside CustomAuthToken.

Comment: or you can see the implementation of token in drf and learn (from the **code which they have written**) and then implement it yourself.

Comment: So, I just changed the Django REST Framework Source code :) Now its working haha. But thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

By Default.  Django REST Framework need username and password. phone_number not required to authentication.

if you really need phone_number in authentication then just validate username, password and phone number and create your token.

By OAUTH 1.0

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user["id"])
```

if you want in response too  use OAUTH 2.0 (JWT)

Comment: I don't use OAuth :/ And where should I put the code

Comment: check this link in token authentication section..

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

by default it is use token authentication. if you want customize then also one example available with new url endpoint. see `class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):`

Comment: Hm, still doesn't work as I aspect, but thank you